# Expect several but not all true

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, chai

Suppose I have an array `arr = [true, false, false, true, false]`.
I wish to assert that exactly two values are true in this array. Obviously, I could do something like this (with lodash):

```
Chai.expect(_.filter(arr, item => item == true)).to.have.length(2)
```

Is there a more Chai-y or Jest-y way to do this?

Comment: You could try something like `expect(arr).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([true, true]))`

Comment: It is not clear if you want to assert that there are two items that are true (and 3 that must be false) or if two items must be true but you don't care about the other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no dedicated method for this. A custom assertion is required.

Closest assertion methods are as follows:

- Jest has [expect.arrayContaining(array)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectarraycontainingarray) assertion function;
- Chai has [expect(array).to.have.members(array)](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members) assertion function.

Both options will not suit because of your expected values being a value type and functions above use `===` for comparison (it can be changed, at least in Chai, but still no difference for our case).

```
// Jest example
describe('arrayContaining', () => {
  const expected = [true, true];

  it('does not match: not enough `true` values received', () => {
    expect([true, false, false]).not.toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(expected));
  });

  it('does not match: not enough toatl values received', () => {
    expect([true]).not.toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(expected));
  });
});
```

Both assertions above will **fail**, it means that these assertion rules/functions can not spot a difference between expected and actual values in the given case.